# How to override some key bindings using Quickly

Tags: application-development, quickly, shortcut-keys

I am developing a native application for Ubuntu using quickly. How can I disable few key bindings such as prevent <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd> from closing the window, and other key combinations?

Comment: You mean do this work using code ?

Comment: Not necessarily, may be changing some file which has keybindings, or even code if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you'd modify the global keybindings managed by Compiz.  However, this would only work for systems using compiz as the window manager.  It requires the `python-compizconfig` module.  BTW, the default for close window is ALT+F4, it's the general settings plugin.

Here's how you could do it programmatically:

```
import compizconfig
context=compizconfig.Context()
commandplugin=context.Plugins['core']
c0=commandplugin.Screen['close_window_key']
defaultkey=c0.Value  # store the oldkey so you can put it back at the end
c0.Value='' # Unset the key
context.Write()   #Note that sometimes you have to pass False to get it to update settings
```

Note that to get many of the settings you can use the `keys()` function to list them (i.e.) `context.Plugins.keys()` as they are mostly just modified dictionaries.

Here's a link to code that helped me figure out how this works, since I can't find any documentation: http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/precise/compizconfig-python/precise/view/head:/src/compizconfig.pyx

What might actually be better, is to capture the destroy or delete-event signal sent to the window and test to see if it actually originated with a keypress.  I wrote some code and was able to test for the keypress, but even though I can prevent the Gtk.main loop from being terminated, I can't prevent the window from being destroyed.  Maybe someone else has an idea about that.

Edit: Here's my code that works correctly, but is there a better way to test for the key combo in the quit_test function?

Edit2: Modified to test for modifier keys and F4 correctly, but this DOES NOT work?!  It will work for if I make it test for `Gdk.ModifierType.CONTROL_MASK`, but MOD1 which should be the Alt key doesn't work.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from gi.repository import Gtk
keypress=True
def quit_test(widget, data):
    global keypress
    print "destroying"

    if keypress:
        keypress=False
        return True
    else:
        Gtk.main_quit()
        widget.destroy()

def handle_keys(widget,event):
    global keypress
    modifiers=Gtk.accelerator_get_default_mod_mask() 
    for mod in dir(Gdk.ModifierType): #just printing what the modifier is
        if (event.state&modifiers) == getattr(Gdk.ModifierType,mod): print mod
    if event.keyval==Gdk.KEY_F4 and (event.state&modifiers)==Gdk.ModifierType.MOD1_MASK:
        keypress=True
    print event.keyval, keypress

win=Gtk.Window()
win.connect('delete-event', quit_test)
win.connect('key-press-event', handle_keys)
label=Gtk.Label("just some text")
win.add(label)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Comment: I do the same in an application where the user shouldn't be able to close the window when fullscreen. In the window `delete-event` handler, just do a `return True` when the keycombo is pressed, else `Gtk.main_quit()`.

Comment: @Timo Yes I found out this method somewhere today only. You should post this as a separate answer. I think that is a better way of dealing with it. Also I will be grateful to you if you can provide an example. I am unable to parse the `function` keys.

Comment: @Timo, Yes please post... I included my code above in an edit, but while the Gtk.quit is avoided, the window is still destroyed. I don't know what I did wrong.

Comment: Actually, figured out what I did wrong... The above now works, but would like to know if there's a better way to test for the key combo, perhaps directly in the quit_test function

Comment: Your code is a bit buggy, `65513L` is the `alt`-key, not `alt+f4`. So when tapping the alt-key and then trying to close by using the window's close button, it will fail. I however haven't been able yet to come up with something better (also a bit lack of time).

Comment: Ok... Made it test directly for F4 and modifier key, but the delete-event must occur before(?) the keypress-event because it doesn't pick it up?! Help... I'd really like to understand this